# Camera Calibration basic doubts

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, camera, camera-calibration

I am starting out with computer vision and opencv. I would like to try camera calibration for the images that I have to see how it works. I have a very basic doubt.

Should I use the same camera from which the distorted images were captured or I can use any camera to perform my camera calibration?

Answer (score 1):

Camera calibration is supposed to do for the same camera. Purpose of calibrating a camera is to understand how much distortion the image has and to correct it before we use it to take actual pics. Even if you do not have the original camera, If you have the checkerboard images taken from that camera it is sufficient. Otherwise, look for a similar camera with features as similar as possible (focal length etc.) to take checker board images for calibration and this will somewhat serve your purpose.